# Как в WPF в Label после текста выводить свои данные?

Tags: wpf, binding, label

В общем есть Label над таблицей в которой выводятся некоторые данные.

```
<Label FontWeight="Bold" Content="Найдено по номеру:"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Название" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Номер" Binding="{Binding Number}" />
```

Как в Label вывести следующую строку: "Найдено по номеру Number и названию Name" ?
Не могу понять как выводить данные в таком порядке.
Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <TextBlock>
        <Run Text="Найдено по номеру" />
        <Run Text="{Binding Number}" />
        <Run Text="и названию" />
        <Run Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

По итогу сделал другим способом:

**Main.xaml:**

```
<Label FontWeight="Bold" Content="{Binding LabelNumberAndName}"/>
```

**MainModel.cs**

```
private string _labelNumberAndName;

public string LabelNumberAndName
        {
            get => _labelNumberAndName;
            set
            {
                if (value == _labelNumberAndName) return;
                _labelNumberAndName= value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(LabelNumberAndName));
            }
        }

private void SetNuberAndName()
{
        LabelNumberAndName = "Найденные по номеру " + Number + " и названию " + Name + ":";
}
```